# Creating multiple regression lines with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a dataframe (data) that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to create a scatter plot using `ggplot()` with regression lines for each level of Mating.system (MO, PG, PR).

So far, I've created this code

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=data$Log.MF.mass, y=data$log.FM.lifespan, group=data$Mating.system)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=data$Mating.system, color=data$Mating.system))
p <- p+labs(x="Log MF body mass", y="Log FM longevity", color="Mating system")
```

This produces two legends, I'd like to remove the bottom one and remove the NA in it too.

[image]

I would like to draw on the three regression lines corresponding to MO, PG, PR on the plot. I hope I have explained this well.

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please provide `data` as plain text, not an image, so users can easily copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be sure without seeing your data, but I think this should work. Some notes:

- Don't use `data$` inside `aes()`; just use the column names
- Do you really need both color and shape for the same variable?
- For regression use `geom_smooth()` and group by factor there; you can add `se = FALSE` to remove the confidence intervals
- Regarding NA, I personally think it should be in the legend to indicate those points that do not have mating system

  ```
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Log.MF.mass, 
                   y = log.FM.lifespan)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = Mating.system, 
                   color = Mating.system)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
                aes(group = Mating.system, 
                    color = Mating.system)) +
    guides(shape = FALSE)
  ```

Comment: You raise a very good point re shapes AND colours - I don't need both. Thanks for your tip about pasting plain text data, will be sure to do that next time. Your script worked perfectly! Cheers

Comment: Good to hear. Please vote and accept the answer if it solved the problem.